# getElementsByTagName where property == value?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a customization for a 3rd party tool, but the JS documentation on their API is a little scarce. The high-level overflow of what I'm trying to do is find all anchor tags where the target property equals "fManager".

Once I have all of these anchor tags, I want to get the onclick property, and set the value to the ontouchend property.

This is the javascript I've built so far:

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {
    if(links[i].getAttribute('target') == 'fManager')
        links[i].setAttribute('ontouchend', links[i].getAttribute('onclick'));
}
```

The problem I see with this code, is that I have the impression it's not efficient. First it gets every anchor tag on the page, and only then it cuts down to the links that match the extra criteria.

Is there a way I can improve this, to say, getElementsByTagName('a') where getAttribute('target') == 'fManager'? Would there be a faster/more efficient way along these lines?

Note: I cannot use 3rd party libraries such as JQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about `querySelectorAll` instead like:

```
var results = document.querySelectorAll('a[target="fManager"]');
```

Comment: This is likely the ideal pure JS answer, but it should be noted that this is not supported in IE7. For most people that may not be a major concern, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks, these seems to be working as well. Also thanks @sphanley for the tip with IE7, I'll have to check whether that'll be an issue or not. Hopefully not. 

If anyone else has alternate suggestions, please do comment. Thanks.